# How can I verify that my application runs with php 5.5.x?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I have an application that is based on SugarCRM CE. The official advise is to use only php5.3 versions. Now that both the community edition of SugarCRM and the support for php5.3 ended I wonder what I can do to verify that everything still works as expected.

On a testing system with php 5.5.10 I have a running installation of the last sugar version 6.5.17. There are some notices in the webservers (nginx) error.log but as it seems nothing serious just notices.

What else should I do to ensure no hidden problems?

Comment: Allways treat E_NOTICE as a critical error. Especialy when unsure if your app is stable.

Comment: You're just going to have to test it more thoroughly. There's no way to be sure that the notices aren't a serious problem without testing it.

Comment: there where some unit tests published by sugar a while ago. I'm goint to add them to the latest version and I 'll pay attention to the notices I promise

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it's a question that I'm looking for answers to. Has anyone managed to do any testing in a PHP 5.5.x environment? It would save me a heck of a lot of work trying to find/install/run some unit tests which are not part of the release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these pages and follow all advices there. There is no "fast and easy" way around this...

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php